# Exception in thread "ajp-bio-8009-exec-1"

Tags: java, tomcat, printwriter

I am facing strange error. My all java code runs without any problem on my laptop (windows 7) but when I upload it to our server (linux) then am seeing following in tomcat log:

```
Exception in thread "ajp-bio-8009-exec-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.System.checkKey(System.java:831)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:705)
    at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:84)
    at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:49)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:116)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
    at mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:50)
    at mig.common.src.SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:71)
    at mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:54)
    at mig.common.src.SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:71)
    at mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:54)
    at mig.common.src.SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:71)
```

Here is my ErrorCheck.errorMsg code:

```
public String errorMsg(String subject, Exception e){    
        String stackTrace = "";                 
        try{
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();  
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);  
                        e.printStackTrace(pw);
                            stackTrace = sw.toString();          
                        stackTrace = stackTrace.replaceAll("\n","<br>");                        SendEmail.send("myemail@gmail.com","toemail@gmail.com",subject,stackTrace);         
                pw.close();
                pw = null;      
            sw.close();
            sw = null;

            System.gc();

        }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }           
    return stackTrace;
    }
```

Please advise.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was as following:

I was writing in my code:

```
ErrorCheck ec = new ErrorCheck();
String error = ec.error();
```

and then was calling in catch block

```
ec.errorMsg(error+"SendEmail.send()", e);
```

I removed from all classes error variable that was storing ec.error(); and corrected in my main class method errorMsg of ErrorCheck.java as following:

```
String finalSubject = error()+subject;
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();  
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);  
                    e.printStackTrace(pw);
```

Now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your program send an email if you have an error. In this case you have an error when sending an email, so you have an "endless loop".

You can see it here:

```
at mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:50)
at mig.common.src.SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:71)
at mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:54)
at mig.common.src.SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:71)
at mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:54)
at mig.common.src.SendEmail.send(SendEmail.java:71)
```

And finally you get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: You are right my program send an email when there is an error and in case if there is an error email shoots up. This process is not in loop but written in exception block. if any exception catched then email is sent to me. There is no loop anywhere

Comment: @Ghayel  I wrote loop in quotes becaus i do not mean a real loop. It is an indirect loop, because send throws an exception which will call errorMsg which will call send and so on. you have to try to find out what is wrong if you send en email. I think there is the problem.

Comment: I don't know why its not giving error in my laptop. When I upload it to our server its start throwing errors and not run my servlet

Comment: @Ghayel can you show an error message. Maybe there is a problem reaching the mail server.

Comment: mig.common.src.ErrorCheck.errorMsg(ErrorCheck.java:50) indicates: PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

Comment: SendEmail.send line is: }catch(Exception e){
   ec.errorMsg(error+"SendEmail.send()", e);
         }

Comment: @Ghayel Try to log the exception also to a logfile, so you can see whats happend.